# Highlight a date range with conditional formating - Dates reference from cells

Tags: date, google-sheets, format, conditional-statements

I have a google sheet with a lot of dates, and I want to highligt dates in the sheet that are between two dates using conditional formation.
I can get it to work if I use between values and enter "=Date(2021;11;1)" and "=Date(2021;11;31)"

I don´t want to open the conditinal formating and change the dates, I want the dates to be in like A1 and B1. How do I do that? - any help appriciated

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

if your dates are in range A3:A use this formula on range A3:A

```
=(A3>=A$1)*(A3<B$1)
```